# Using summarise and across in the dplyr package while distinguishing between numeric and non-numeric columns

Tags: r, dplyr, numeric, across

I would like to perform some operations using `dplyr` on a dataset that looks like:

```
data <- data.frame(day = c(rep(1, 15), rep(2, 15)), nweek = rep(rep(1:5, 3),2), 
                   firm = rep(sapply(letters[1:3], function(x) rep(x, 5)), 2), 
                   quant = rnorm(30), price = runif(30) )
```

where each observation is at the day, week and firm level (there're only 2 days in a week).

I would like to summarise the data (grouping by `firm`) by (1) taking average across the days of the week `across` variables that are `numeric` (i.e., `quant` and `price`), and to take the first entry for variables that are not numeric (in this case it is only `firm`, but in my real dataset I have multiple variables that are not numeric (`Date` and `character`) and they may change within a week (`nweek`), so I would like to take only the entry in the first day of the week for all the non-numeric variables.

I tried using `summarise` and `across` but get an error

```
> data %>% group_by(firm, nweek) %>% dplyr::summarise(across(which(sapply(data, is.numeric)), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)),
+                           across(which(sapply(data, !(is.numeric))), ~ head(.x, 1))
+ )
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..2`.
x invalid argument type
ℹ Input `..2` is `across(which(sapply(data, !(is.numeric))), ~head(.x, 1))`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what your expected output should look like, but something like this could reach what you are trying to achieve

```
data %>%
  group_by(firm, nweek) %>% 
  summarise(
    across(where(is.numeric), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)),
    across(!where(is.numeric), ~ head(.x, 1))
)
```

As a sidenote, instead of using `which(sapply(...))`, have a look at the `where` helper for conditional selection of variables inside `across` in this [post](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html).

Output

```
# A tibble: 15 x 5
# Groups:   firm [3]
   firm  nweek   day   quant price
   <chr> <int> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a         1   1.5 -0.336  0.903
 2 a         2   1.5  0.0837 0.579
 3 a         3   1.5  0.0541 0.425
 4 a         4   1.5  1.21   0.555
 5 a         5   1.5  0.462  0.806
 6 b         1   1.5  0.0493 0.346
 7 b         2   1.5  0.635  0.596
 8 b         3   1.5  0.406  0.583
 9 b         4   1.5 -0.707  0.205
10 b         5   1.5  0.157  0.816
11 c         1   1.5  0.728  0.271
12 c         2   1.5  0.117  0.775
13 c         3   1.5 -1.05   0.234
14 c         4   1.5 -1.35   0.290
15 c         5   1.5  0.771  0.310
```